# Multithreading - Alternating between two threads using Conditions and Events in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, events, synchronization

I am trying to write a program using which I wish to alternate between two threads, thread1 and thread2. The tricky part is that the thread should begin execution first must be thread1.
This is the code I have so far:

```
Class Client:
#member variables
def sendFile(self,cv1,lock1):

        sent=0;
        while (i<self.size):
            message = self.data[i:1024+i]
            cv1.acquire()
            BadNet.transmit(self.clientSocket,message,self.serverIP,self.serverPort)
            cv1.notify() 
            cv1.release()

            i = i+1024
            sent+=1
            lock1.wait()

        print "File sent successfully !"   
        self.clientSocket.close()

    def receiveAck(self,cv1,lock2):
        i=0
        while (1):
            lock1.clear()
            cv1.acquire()
            cv1.wait()
            print "\nentered ack !\n"
            self.ack, serverAddress = self.clientSocket.recvfrom(self.buf)

            cv1.release()
            lock1.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock1 = Event()
    cv1 = Condition()
    cv2= Condition()
    client = Client();
    client.readFile();

    thread1 = Thread(target = client.sendFile, args=[cv1,lock1])
    thread2 = Thread(target = client.receiveAck, args=[cv1,lock1])

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

The problem I am currently facing is that initially the program does alternate between two threads (confirmed by the output on the console. But after an arbitrary number of iterations (usually between 20 and 80) the program just hangs and no further iterations are performed.

Comment: My first question is, why do you want this? What's the point of having two threads if they're just trading off control explicitly, which you can do more easily with, say, a generator?

Comment: I just simplified my program for understanding purposes. Whats happening actually is that thread1 uses a UDP socket to send a packet while thread2 uses the same socket to receive acknowledgment for that packet. Thread1 is not supposed to proceed unless acknowledgment for previous packet has been received.
I hope you got my point, but even if you don't I would request that you ignore my purpose of alternating between two threads and kindly help with the issue that I am facing.

Comment: Sound fairly sequential... Why use threads instead of simply using blocking IO? block until you get your ACK and then move on to the next packet in a loop, why threads?

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're not using the condition right on the waiter side. You have to have a loop around checking the condition and calling `cv1.wait()` inside the `acquire`/`release` pair, or you're just using a cv as a broken event+lock combination. More importantly, you don't see to have any condition to protect with a cv in the first place. If, e.g., the socket were non-blocking, and you checked for `recvfrom` not being ready, that would be something to protect with a cv, but you're not doing that.

Comment: Also, giving us a fully running example (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) that we can debug would make things a lot easier; instead of guessing at what _could_ be wrong in your code, we could figure out what _is_ wrong.

Comment: Another obvious problem is that you're using the event wrong. The receive thread sets the event and then, as fast as possible, clears it. If the send thread doesn't get to the wait before this point (which is easily possible), it will wait forever.

Comment: Finally, "I would request that you ignore my purpose…" is not necessarily a reasonable request. It's very hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish here; you're using the sync objects in ways that don't make any sense, and leaving it up to us to guess what you actually wanted to do. Explaining why you wanted to do so may make it a lot easier to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your synchronization.

First, you're using `cv1` wrong. Your receive thread has to *loop* around its cv, checking the condition and calling `wait` each time. Otherwise, you're just using a cv as a broken event + lock combination. You don't have such a loop. More importantly, you don't even have a condition to wait for.

Second, you're using `lock1` wrong. Your receive thread sets the event and then immediately clears it. But there's no guarantee that the send thread has gotten to the wait yet. (The race from the previous problem makes this more of a problem, but it's still a problem even if you fix that.) On a multi-core machine, it will *usually* get there in time, but "usually" is even worse than never in threaded programming. So, eventually the send thread will get to the wait after the receive thread has already done the clear, and therefore it will wait forever. The receive thread, meanwhile, will be waiting to be notified by the send thread, which will never happen. So you're deadlocked.

For future reference, adding `print` statements before and after every blocking operation, especially sync operations, would make this a lot to debug: you would see the receive thread's last message was "receive waiting on cv1", while the send thread's last message was "send waiting on lock1", and it would be obvious where the deadlock was.

---

Anyway, I'm not sure what it would even mean to "fix" a cv with no condition, or an event that you're trying to use as a cv, so instead I'll show how to write something sensible with two cvs. In this case, we might as well just use a flag that we flip back and forth as the condition for both cvs.

While I'm at it, I'll fix a couple other problems that made your code not even testable (e.g., `i` is never initialized), and include the debugging information, and what I had to fill in to make this a complete example, but otherwise I'll try to leave your structure and irrelevant problems (like `Client` being an old-style class) intact.

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.serverIP = '127.0.0.1'
        self.serverPort = 11111
        self.buf = 4
        self.waitack = False

    def readFile(self):
        self.data = ', '.join(map(str, range(100000)))
        self.size = len(self.data)

    #member variables
    def sendFile(self,cv1,lock1):
        i = 0
        sent=0
        while (i<self.size):
            message = self.data[i:1024+i]
            print "s cv1 acquire"
            with cv1:
                print "s sendto"
                self.clientSocket.sendto(message, (self.serverIP, self.serverPort))
                self.waitack = True
                print "s cv1 notify"
                cv1.notify() 

            i = i+1024
            sent+=1

            print "s cv2 acquire"
            with cv2:
                print "s cv2 wait"
                while self.waitack:
                    cv2.wait()

        print "File sent successfully !"   
        self.clientSocket.close()

    def receiveAck(self,cv1,lock2):
        i=0
        while (1):
            print "r cv1 acquire"
            with cv1:
                while not self.waitack:
                    print "r cv1 wait"
                    cv1.wait()
            print "r recvfrom"
            self.ack, serverAddress = self.clientSocket.recvfrom(self.buf)
            i += 1
            print self.ack, i            

            print "r cv2 acquire"
            with cv2:
                self.waitack = False
                print "r cv2 notify"
                cv2.notify()
```

And here's a test server for it:

```
from itertools import *
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 11111))

for i in count():
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print(i)
    s.sendto('ack\n', addr)
```

Start the server, start the client, the server will count up to 672, the client will count up to 673 (since your code counts 1-based) with 673 balanced pairs of messages and a "File sent successfully !" at the end. (Of course the client will then hang forever because `receiveAck` has no way to finish, and the server because I wrote it as an infinite loop.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It worked perfectly as I had intended to do with my original code. My apologies for not providing a fully functional code, Ill be careful next time. As for the issue of using threads to do perform a fairly sequential task, that was actually a requirement for this assignment I am working on !